# android studio - unwanted infinite error logs

Tags: android, android-studio

On my android studio, the following error, rapidly and infinitely gets logged without stop, making it hard to detect other logs.

```
2020-04-18 01:03:52.331 28206-12320/? E/Finsky: [2244] prj.a(3): Replication failed, request pending true
    java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
        at apow.a(PG:2)
        at apow.get(PG:11)
        at aprr.a(PG:1)
        at apqn.a(PG:21)
        at apqj.run(PG:3)
        at kjg.execute(PG:1)
        at apow.b(PG:20)
        at apow.a(PG:16)
        at apow.a(PG:36)
        at appa.run(PG:3)
        at apqy.run(Unknown Source:7)
        at kjg.execute(PG:1)
        at apqz.execute(PG:1)
        at appv.b(PG:1)
        at appv.a(PG:3)
        at apqu.done(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.cancel(FutureTask.java:181)
        at apqf.cancel(Unknown Source:4)
        at kjy.cancel(Unknown Source:2)
        at psa.a(PG:19)
        at psa.a(PG:24)
        at pro.run(Unknown Source:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at kjd.run(Unknown Source:14)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: You can filter the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filtering the logcat:

[image]